# Why is alembic upgrade not working on test database in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, alembic

I am pretty new to testing in general. I am using postgreSQL and SQLAlchemy for databases, FastAPI backend and Alembic for migrations. I want to set up a test database for testing. I have custom migration scripts that I want to execute on my test database. Here is a sample `test_users` file.

```
import pytest
import alembic
from alembic.config import Config

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database, database_exists, drop_database
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
`
TEST_DB_URL = f"{DATABASE_URL}_test"

if database_exists(TEST_DB_URL):
    drop_database(TEST_DB_URL)

create_database(TEST_DB_URL)

alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
alembic_cfg.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', str(TEST_DB_URL))
alembic.command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")

engine = create_engine(TEST_DB_URL)
TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def connection():
    connection = engine.connect()
    yield connection
    connection.close()

@pytest.fixture
def session(connection):
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session = TestingSessionLocal(bind=connection)
    yield session
    session.close()
    transaction.rollback()
    # drop_database(TEST_DB_URL)

@pytest.fixture()
def client(session):
    def override_get_db():
        yield session

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
    client = TestClient(app)
    yield client
    del app.dependency_overrides[get_db]

def test_user_register(client):
    response = client.post("/register", json={"email": "def@def.com", "master_pwd": "pass"})
    print(response)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

But as I am checking pgadmin, the test database is created but the migrations are not being applied, and running pytest gives 404 error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I face the same problem. Were you able to overcome it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an older thread, but I faced the same issue and this popped up on my Google search.

In my case, the problem is that in my `env.py` I have the following line:

```
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", settings.DATABASE_URL)
```

Where `settings.DATABASE_URL` is a variable that contains the db connection read from an environment variable (to avoid hard-coding it in the `alembic.ini` file).

Now when you call `alembic.command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")` the `env.py` is implicitly run as well and overrides your `alembic_cfg.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', str(TEST_DB_URL))` back to the real DATABASE_URL.

I solved this by mocking my `settings` module via

```
from core import settings as mocked_settings
mocked_settings.DATABASE_URL = TEST_DB_URL
mocker.patch.dict("sys.modules", {"core.settings": mocked_settings})
```

where `mocker` refers to the fixture from the `pytest-mock` module (you can use the standard library `mock` as well though).

In case you read the database URL directly from an environment variable in your `env.py` it might be even easier:

```
mocker.patch.dict("os.environ", DATABASE_URL=TEST_DB_URL)
```

Hope that helps others! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above approach is to setup the `alembic_engine` in your `tests/conftest.py` file:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def alembic_engine():
    """Override this fixture to provide pytest-alembic powered tests with a database handle.
    """
    test_db = set_up_empty_test_db()   # Whatever this means in your code..
    try:
        sqlalchemy_url = f"..."  # whatever your test cx string would be
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(sqlalchemy_url)
    except Exception as e:
        test_db.stop()  # whatever your cleanup logic requires
        raise e

    yield engine

    test_db.stop()  # whatever your cleanup logic requires
```

And then, in your `env.py` check for an existing connection and use it if present (pytest-alembic will set it at startup):

```
def run_migrations_online():
    # When running pytest-alembic the connection will be pre-populated
    connectable = context.config.attributes.get("connection", None)

    if connectable is None:
        connectable = engine_from_config(...  # regular alembic

    # The with statement on down is unchanged
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
       ...
```

See the setup docs for further details: https://pytest-alembic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html